# call IIdentityServiceBuilder.AddSigningCredential in the Configure method

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

Please help me with `IIdentityServerBuilder.AddSigningCredential` call in the `Startup.Configure` method.

I'm loading key material for the IdentityServer4 in the `ConfigureServices` method like below:

```
class Startup
{
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
                services.AddScoped<KeyVaultAccessImpl>();

                var identityBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer();

                KeyVaultAccessImpl kva;
                kva = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<KeyVaultAccessImpl>();
                foreach (X509Certificate2 c in kva.LoadSignCertificates())
                    identityBuilder.AddSigningCredential(c);
        }
}
```

The `AddSigningCredential` method is called in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.
The `KeyVaultAccessImpl` implementation loads `X509Certificate2` instances from the external store to be used in the `identityBuilder.AddSigningCredential`.
The `KeyVaultAccessImpl` contains external dependencies that are configured with `services.Add...`

It works fine, however calling `services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<KeyVaultAccessImpl>()` in the `ConfigureServices` method produces compiler warning:

> Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'

I've tried to store the `identityBuilder` as class property and call `AddSigningCredential` in the `Configure` method like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddScoped<KeyVaultAccessImpl>();

        identityBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer();
    }

IIdentityServerBuilder identityBuilder;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, KeyVaultAccessImpl kva)
{
        foreach (X509Certificate2 c in kva.LoadSignCertificates())
            identityBuilder.AddSigningCredential(c); // no error but key is not added
        identityBuilder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential() //is ignored either
        app.UseIdentityServer();

}
```

However the problem is that the AddSigningCredential is ignored and no key is added actually.

The error `PolicyViolation Keyset is missing` is raised when I'm trying to get the token.

Probably because IdentityServer is created (and initialized) after `ConfigureServices` but before `Configure` method is called.

Can I call `identityBuilder.AddSigningCredential` in the `Configure` method somehow ?

Comment: So just looking at your code I would go with instantianting `KeyVaultAccessImpl` yourself, retrieving keys, and then adding them through `IIdentityServerBuilder ` as you are you doing now. Basically `kva = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<KeyVaultAccessImpl>();` -> `kva = new KeyVaultAccessImpl();`

Comment: `KeyVaultAccessImpl` takes external dependencies (like config and KeyVaultClient factory) so that is why I'm using the `.GetService<>`. The `KeyVaultAccessImpl` is used not only for IdenitityServer configuration so it would be nice to have it from the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to implement your own `ISigningCredentialStore` and `IValidationKeysStore` that take the `KeyVaultAccessImpl` as a dependency. They can then call that service at runtime as needed.

Check this out to see how the default `AddSigningCredential()` builder method works:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/DependencyInjection/BuilderExtensions/Crypto.cs

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, @mackie

I've created `CredentialStore` to implement `ISigningCredentialStore` and `IValidationKeysStore` as below

```
/// <summary>
/// implementation of signing and validation stores, 
/// loads X509Certificate from the KeyVault
/// </summary>
public class CredentialStore : ISigningCredentialStore, IValidationKeysStore
{
    private readonly KeyVaultAccessImpl kva;

    public CredentialStore(KeyVaultAccessImpl kva)
    {
        this.kva = kva;
        loadedCertificate = new Lazy<X509Certificate2>(() => LoadCertificate());
    }

    public Task<SigningCredentials> GetSigningCredentialsAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Load());
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<SecurityKeyInfo>> GetValidationKeysAsync()
    {
        var credential = Load();

        var keyInfo = new SecurityKeyInfo
        {
            Key = credential.Key,
            SigningAlgorithm = credential.Algorithm
        };

        var res = (IEnumerable<SecurityKeyInfo>) new[] { keyInfo };

        return Task.FromResult(res);
    }

    X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        var cert = kva.LoadCertificate().Result;
        if (!cert.HasPrivateKey)
            throw new ArgumentException($"no private key for certificate {cert.Thumbprint} was found");
        return cert;
    }

    Lazy<X509Certificate2> loadedCertificate;

    SigningCredentials Load(string signingAlgorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
    {
        var key = new X509SecurityKey(loadedCertificate.Value);
        key.KeyId += signingAlgorithm;

        return new SigningCredentials(key, signingAlgorithm);
    }
}
```

Then it is possible to add singletons in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` without `services.BuildServiceProvider()` call:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISigningCredentialStore, CredentialStore>()
    .AddSingleton<IValidationKeysStore, CredentialStore>();
```

Comment: Nice, happy to help :)